# How to get Calculated Formula with Maatwebsite Excel without Import

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I want to ask this question because of the problem that I cannot access App\Import.
Currently, I can read the Excel file with the creation of new collection. However, I didn't get any calculated formula.

```
$theCollection = Excel::toCollection(collect([]), $item, 'custom', \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLSX);
```

When a cell contains "=1+1", the result I got from $theCollection is a string "=1+1" instead of 2.
As I couldn't create an Import Class, I wasn't able to use WithCalculatedFormulas.
How can I get the result of Formula?
Thank you all.

Comment: I hve same question? Did You found solution?

Answer (score 0):

If your Excel file contains calculated formulas and you want to import the calculated values into the database, you'll need to modify the approach slightly. The maatwebsite/excel package doesn't inherently calculate formulas, as it mainly focuses on reading and writing data.

```php
$file = storage_path('path_to_your_excel_file.xlsx'); // Replace with your Excel file path
$spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($file);
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = Coordinate::columnIndexFromString($worksheet->getHighestColumn());

for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
    $rowData = [];
    for ($col = 1; $col <= $highestColumn; ++$col) {
        $cellValue = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getCalculatedValue();
        $rowData[] = $cellValue;
    }

    YourModel::create([
        'column1' => $rowData[0], // Replace with your column names
        'column2' => $rowData[1],
        // Add more columns as needed
    ]);
}
```